# indexed UITableView as Part scrollable Page

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'd like to implement an Interface that shows an indexed UITableView. In the table view I want a view displaying labels and image views related to the table view.
Together they should behave as if they were on one scrollable page.

First I tried to solve the problem with a tableHeaderView (not a section header). But the problem is that the section index overlaps the tableViewHeader.[section index overlaps the table header view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTxDY.png)
If have seen approaches to solve a similar problem with a UISearchBar, but I can apply them to me problem

Then I tried to embed the tableview as a container view into a container view[table view in a containerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1F0A.png)
The problem here is that you can scroll the tableView inside of the container View, while the top view is still visible.

I also though about fading the index in when the content offset is equal to the height of the top view. But there seems to be no official way to get a hold of index bar view.

Any ideas?